# WebApi Parameter binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, modelbinders

I have a webapi which clients use to integrate with. We use both the FromUri and the FromBody parameters which take in complex objects

On the FromUri I have a custom binder which allows clients to send in data with alternate names. So for example, they would send in FN=Bob in the query string and that would map to FirstName property in the complex object. (implemented in this way [Bind Alias Attribute](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/bind-a-model-property-to-a-different-named-query-string-field.html)), this uses a custom model binder as so .. [FromUri(BinderType = typeof(CustomAliasModelBinder))]

Now, my problem lies with teh FromBody parameter. Is there a way to use the custom model binder on the FromBody attribute? Ive tried using [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomAliasModelBinder))] and all sorts to get it to bind.

If I send in the full name for each field (so sending in firstname=Bob instead of FN=Bob) it all works as expected using the standard [FromBody], but I really need it to run through the custom binder. Ive tried getting value providers and RouteData but have am getting nowhere as value provider is always null. (example below)

```
foreach (var property in bindingContext.PropertyMetadata)
        {
            var valueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(property.Key);
            if (valueProvider != null)
            {
                var value = valueProvider.ConvertTo(property.Value.ModelType);
                var pInfo = bindingContext.ModelType.GetProperty(property.Key);
                pInfo.SetValue(model, value, new object[] { });
            }
        }
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.